# Why am I redirected to http://stackoverflow.com/?t=repeatingalarm after login?

Tags: support, login

After login, I was redirected to `https://stackoverflow.com/?t=repeatingalarm` ... What does that mean?

Specifically, `t=repeatingalarm` sounds alarming ... This is the first time I am seeing this.

Comment: I'd answer that for you, but first I have to figure out why this siren is going off in my office and how I can turn it off.

Comment: [mawp](https://i.imgur.com/KIsXM6h.gif?noredirect)

Comment: Leave the building now.

Comment: _Fire - exclamation mark - fire - exclamation mark - help me - exclamation mark. Looking forward to hearing from you._

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/3o6UBpHgaXFDNAuttm/giphy.gif

Comment: The real question is, is it a *repeating alarm* or *rep eating alarm*.  If it is the latter we need to find out who is eating your rep.

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Try this on a different browser. It will help rule out a lot of server side issues if it's specific to your particular browser.

Comment: @NathanOliver or it could be a *rep eating a larm* in which case never mind what the hell a larm is, our rep have come to life!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Well, I can confirm what you report. From our web logs, it looks like you landed (`GET`) on `/` (no query-string), then the next `GET` is on `/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f%3ft%3drepeatingalarm` (which is url-encoded for `https://stackoverflow.com/?t=repeatingalarm`). So the interesting question to me is... *where did that `returnurl` come from?*. I've checked our core codebase, and `repeatingalarm` isn't there. I will do some more digging into our auxiliary tools, but I wonder if it is possible whether this came from a browser plugin of some kind.

It isn't something that has some special meaning to us or our code, as far as I know (yet).

By contrast - if I do this in an incognito Chrome window, the login link is `returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f`

Update:

It looks like fallout from the tag [repeatingalarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeatingalarm) and the `[OutputCache]` not differentiating on the `t` in the query-string; in future, the homepage will include `"t"` in the [`VaryByParam`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.varybyparam(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Haven't installed/updated any plugins recently. You can probably see that I always use the same login method, and I haven't changed that either. Hmmmm  ...

Comment: @SinanÜnür most of the login is between you and your openid provider - we don't see that in our logs, but yes, I have the same provider as you and it seems fine for me...

Comment: I guess I should close this, because I cannot reproduce it, and it doesn't seem to be due to SO code. The intarwebs don't know about it either https://www.google.com/search?q=t%3Drepeatingalarm

Comment: @SinanÜnür it seems to impact a very small number of users (5 times in the last 2 days), but from at least 3 countries and using completely different OSes and browsers; very intriguing

Comment: The fact that you can find this single event among all the tens? hundreds? thousands? hundreds of thousands of similar events in your web logs both fills me with awe and dread.

Comment: @Will so it turns out that computers are pretty good at storing and querying vast quantities of similar data... who knew?

Comment: We should  make use of that property one day.

Comment: Whenever I see IIS logs I curl up into a ball and cry.

Comment: @will perhaps there should be a tool to which you put what you're looking for and it would give you exactly that. Maybe they'll even start packing them with OSes like Linux, that's how useful it would be. Something like grep, but smarter.

Comment: @will, Microsoft's Log Parser (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) lets you scan a folder full of log files with a SQL query (not T-SQL). You will want to put the query in a separate parameter file, and use a cmd file so you don't need to remember all the parameters.

Comment: Are you *trying* to scare me???

Comment: I don't understand the update explanation, what is Marc trying to say?

Comment: @Goose we cache a number of pages for anonymous users, including the homepage. If someone is logging in: they are anonymous. You have to tell the cache by what request pieces to differentiate the requests. `t` wasn't in the list. So  anonymous user "A" visits `/?t=foo` (somehow) - then another anonymous user "B" can be given their cached page with that in the return URL. Not sure where we use this `t`, but it happens a lot in the logs for multiple tags.

Comment: So does this mean I can go to http://stackoverflow.com/?hellothisistheinternetspeaking=unicorns while logged out, and that URL could appear when somebody else logs in?

Comment: @Dave it is a question I had already asked myself - theoretically, possibly - and I'll check/fix next week. It doesn't actually *matter* as such, but it should be fixed

Comment: @MarcGravell I just did that, Hopefully someone notices. (Assuming it has not been fixed.)