# Performance of the "Questions that may already have your answer"

Tags: support, statistics

Related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335166/792066), can we get some data of how it fare in a real world scenario?

Data on:

- Amount of questions shown
- Amount of questions shown in the first 5~6 (whatever is immediately visible)
- Status of both above (has answers, score, closed, etc.)
- How many click through (maybe the status of the question they clicked too?)
- What the asker did afterwards:

  - Whenever it clicked or not, did ask the question anyways?
- What happened to the questions asked by:

  - If was show good (positive score, any other "good" metric) question
  - If was show bad (negative score, closed, any other "bad" metric) question
  - If clicked good (positive score, any other "good" metric) question
  - If clicked bad (negative score, closed, any other "bad" metric) question

I hope this is part of what SE logs... I mean, [they log pretty much anything.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332187/why-am-i-redirected-to-http-stackoverflow-com-t-repeatingalarm-after-login/332202#comment382057_332202)

Comment: I hope this doesn't require any [blood sacrifice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322016/how-many-people-use-filters-in-the-review#comment338644_322016)... right?

Comment: @hicr that data is only available to SE employees, like [every other stats requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+%5Bstatistics%5D+is%3Aq)

Comment: That didn't ping me... apparently mSO is quite weird, [look at mSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion+statistics). But seriously, you're not asking for support -- you're asking for a discussion.

Comment: @hichris123 I want to discuss nothing. I want hard data. Not opinions. I've got that several times http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+%5Bstatistics%5D+is%3Aq+user:792066

Comment: ... and how is that support? I don't really care, but support is "A request for assistance with one of the site's features.", which isn't asking for hard data.

Comment: @hichris123 if you don't care, leave the question *as is*. I know what I'm doing.

Comment: I was more saying "of all the minutiae to be arguing about, this is very unimportant" but okay...